# No EFI boot possible with Clover EFI

Tags: boot, bios, bootloader, sony-vaio, efi

So I have this Vaio Duo 11 sitting next to me, and it works very nice. But to have some sort of bootloader which also is compatible with Hackintosh, I wanted to install Clover. I used my MacBook Air and the myHack utillity to create a new OS X image (also called a myHack image) and made sure my usb drive was formated using GPT, so I was able to put a bootloader into it. It works. I can perfectly boot the Chamelion install from the disk when having my Vaio in Legacy-Mode (Yes, there is no hybrid-mode -.-). But when I then try to boot Clover, it error's about. On the screen I see this:

```
Checking media... [Fail!]
Checking media... [Fail!]
Operating system not found.
```

It appears to me that it can not find the Clover files for booting. Actually, I renamed them. In the following, I'll use {EFI} to describe the efi partition. Now, I use the following file structure:

- {EFI}/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi
- {EFI}/EFI/BOOT/BOOTIA32.efi

Originally, this looked like the two lines above, but instead of BOOT, they used CLOVER.

- {EFI}/EFI/CLOVER/CLOVERX64.efi

I heared that Clover was able to boot my legacy-devices while being in UEFI mode. And since Mac OS won't start up when I directly boot it thru EFI, and a different bootloader, I appearently need to use chamelion.

Comment: We cannot help install OS X on non-Apple hardware here at Superuser

Comment: @Ramhound: Its more the EFI booting thats the problem, im not asking for help for the install tiself. I know that myself and am aware, but the EFI booting is a problem that i thought could be helped with o.o'

Comment: Did you try asking in their [forum](http://www.osx86.net/guides-tutorials/19291-guide-clover-efi-bootloader.html)? Did you try rEFInd already?

Comment: @Karan: I thought rEFInd only works on Macs themselves o-o . I use rEFIt on my MBA.

Comment: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows